# I want to send a textBox value in email in C#. some one Help me?

Tags: c#

I want to send a textBox value in email in C#. some one Help me?

Answer (score 3):

see Scott Gu's article to send Sending Email with System.Net.Mail [here](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2005/12/16/432854.aspx).

Load the body of the mail with the TextBox.Text value

Answer (score 2):

```
txtBox.Text;
```

will give you the value in C#

[TextBox.Text Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.textbox.text.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

you can try something like this

```
MailMessage msg = new MailMessage();
msg.From = "test@mail.com";
msg.To.Add("rec@mail.com");
msg.Subject = "test";
msg.Body = yourTextbox.Text

SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient();
smtpClient.Host = _smtpHostName; //host name
smtpClient.Port = _smtpPort; //required port
smtpClient.Send(msg);
```

Have a look at

[SmtpClient Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.smtpclient.aspx)

and [SmtpClient Constructor (String, Int32)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/67w4as51.aspx)